# Use all processor cores, 1 core/per 1 thread in *nix

Tags: linux, unix, cpu, multi-core, threads

According to xz documentation the "-T 4" means I should be using 4 threads, each compressing a different part of the file simultaneously.

Before using nice -19 I would only get %50 usage of 1 core, Now how do I use the other 3 cores?(these aren't virtual cores either, they're real)

nice -19 xz -v9ekC sha256 -T 4 /path/to/file.tar

[image: only 1 processor over %50 at time!!]

Comment: Which version of `xz` are you using?

Comment: How fast is your IO? If you can not read fast enough from disk (or disk cache) then throwing more cores at it will not help. Are you testing with a huge file ?

Comment: @jjlin 5.1.0alpha

Comment: @Hennes `xz` compression is very much CPU-bound, unless you have a pretty unusual hardware configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Multithreaded coding wasn't implemented until 5.1.1alpha:

http://git.tukaani.org/?p=xz.git;a=blob;f=NEWS;hb=HEAD

This is easy to verify if you compare `src/xz/coder.c` for the 5.1.0alpha and 5.1.1alpha (just search for "thread").

Comment: Before I mark this as accepted, I'd like to test it 1st. I guess I'll have to wait til 5.1.1alpha or higher is released for ubuntu; I've been looking for an excuse to install funtoo linux.

Comment: It's actually pretty straightforward to just download the source and compile it yourself. I don't recall `xz` having any uncommon external dependencies.